# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd and I am seeing this error

> findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DOMWrap which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference

I have realized that it is because of `mode="horizontal"`.
I have tried using other components as well and I see this error a lot in antd. Is there any way to fix this issue?
This is my current code

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Layout, Menu  } from 'antd';

const { Header, Footer, Content } = Layout;

  const AddForm = () => {
    return (
    <div>
        {/* // Menu Starts from here */}

        <Layout className="layout">
            <Header>
            <div className="logo" />
            <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={['2']}>
                <Menu.Item key="1">nav 1</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="2">nav 2</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="3">nav 3</Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
            </Header>
            <Content style={{ padding: '0 50px' }}>
            <div className="site-layout-content">Content</div>
            </Content>
            <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED</Footer>
        </Layout>
    </div>
    )

  };
```

Comment: This is an open issue

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22493

Comment: This issue isn't unique to `antd`, I'm seeing the same in `material-ui`, I've had to use `React.forwardRef` to resolve it - and in some cases I couldn't. Assume library authors need to drop backwards compatibility at some point and stop using `findDOMNode`.

Comment: I've wrote up a similar issue on StackOverflow for `material-ui`. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63365573/11705601

Answer (score 1):

I'm fixing it by wrapping the commponent using <React.StrictMode>

in my case, the the button inside the form caused that error, so I solve it by

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="submit">
        Register
    </Button>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about it. You have to wait for `antd` to support Strict Mode. Yet, you can consider contributing to the project.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic team has issued that they are fixing the issue:

See here https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4050

The best work around I presume is using plain semantic-ui instead of hacking react.

```
<button className="ui button large primary">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone facing this warning, I managed to resolve it by upgrading ant to "antd": "4.20.7", and the issue disappeared. I am using react version 17.0.2.

I think it was resolved in newer release of antd, however, I could not find any reference online.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is no good alternaive for `findDOMNode` in React 16: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22493

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, I am adding this at the root file.
I'm suppressing the warning like so:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const consoleError = console.error.bind(console);
// eslint-disable-next-line
console.error = (errObj, ...args) => {
  if (
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && typeof errObj.message === 'string' && args.includes('findDOMNode')
  ) {
    return;
  }
  consoleError(errObj, ...args);
};
```

I know this is not a fix, but at least my console is not bloated with `findDOMNode` messages. Until And-Design fixes this, this will do.